# Problem with host, with minikube + nginx ingress

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: emotive44/auth
          env:
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jwt-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30000
```

This is my auth service and deployment.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myapp.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: "Prefix"
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

That is my Ingress file.

When I run commnand: `minikube start`, the message, which I received is:

> StartHost failed, but will try again: provision: get ssh host-port: get port 22 for "minikube": docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exit status 1

`kubectl get ingress`, returns:

```
NAME             CLASS     HOSTS     ADDRESS          PORTS  AGE 
ingress-service  <none>   myapp.com  192.168.49.2      80     106m
```

In my windows host file I add: `192.168.49.2 myapp.com`

And if I try to open myapp.com in browser: There is no access to this site

`curl myapp.com`

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to myapp.com port 80: Timed out

This is describe for my ingress:

```
Name:             ingress-service
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.49.2
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  myapp.com
              /api/users/?(.*)   auth-srv:3000 (172.17.0.2:3000)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Hello @markostreleshki and welcome to Stack Overflow :) This looks like a minikube connection issue rather than Ingress one. Could you please tell us: 1. Which minikube driver you use? How did you spawn nginx-ngress? Have you tried to curl using NodePort?

Comment: Hello Wytrzymaly Wiktor, Thank you. The problem was that by default minikube use driver=docker, but ingress-controller is not capability to work with it. I run minikube delete, and after that run: minikube start --driver=hyperv. And now everything works correctly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [known issues](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/#known-issues) of docker driver for minikube says:

> - The `ingress`, and `ingress-dns` addons are currently only supported on Linux. See [#7332](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7332)

It also applies to Windows:

```
$ minikube addons enable ingress
* Due to docker networking limitations on windows, ingress addon is not supported for this driver.
Alternatively to use this addon you can use a vm-based driver:

        'minikube start --vm=true'

To track the update on this work in progress feature please check:
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7332
```

The solution for this is to use the [hyperv driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/):

> Hyper-V is a native hypervisor built in to modern versions of
> Microsoft Windows.

Recreating your minikube cluster with `--driver=hyperv` flag will fix your issue.